# Set of all subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$ are uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

How to prove that the set of all subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$ are uncountable? I have no idea about it. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Let $P$ be the set of primes. Consider the map defined on $S(P)$ the set of subsets of $P$, which associates to the subset $U$, the subring $S(U)$ generated by $\{1/p,p\in U\}$. Show that this map is injective.

Comment: ok i am going to check one one of this map....if possible please write some thing about injection....thanks a lot...

Comment: yes i got it....thanks a lot.....